# Add values to data frames in list based on names

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I'm sure this must have been asked before, but I can't find the answer.

I have a list of data frames, like so:

```
x  <- c(2, 3, 5)
y <- c("a", "b", "c")
df1 <- data.frame(x, y)

x <- c(3, 6, 9)
y <- c("a", "b", "c")
df2 <- data.frame(x, y)

ls <- list(df1, df2)
names(ls) <- c("example1", "example2")
```

What I would like to do is create a new column, text_id, based upon the name of the data frame. I can do this for a specific data frame as follows:

```
ls[[1]]$text_id <- names(ls[1])
```

I thought I understood how `lapply()` works, but I obviously don't, because this doesn't work:

```
ls2 <- lapply(ls, function(x){
ls[[x]]$text_id <- names(ls[x])
return(ls2)})
```

Instead, I get `Error in ls[x] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

I tried `as.data.frame` before subsetting, but that didn't work either. And I'm also not sure whether the value of the return should be `ls2`, but I haven't got that far yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `Map`

```
Map(cbind, ls, text_id=names(ls))
```